# Typescript function taking one or array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

We are using simple function declaration quite a lot where function takes either single object or array of objects of some type.

Simple declaration is:

```
interface ISomeInterface {
    name: string;
}

class SomeClass {
    public names: ISomeInterface[] = [];

    public addNames(names: ISomeInterface | ISomeInterface[]): void {
        names = (!Array.isArray(names)) ? [names] : names;
        this.names = this.names.concat(names);
    }    
}
```

But TypeScript throws "type is not assignable" error.

Is there better way of doing this? Obviously we could have two separate functions, but I think handling single vs multiple this way is quite fine.

Comment: Protip: instead of isArray,  use names = [].concat(names). 43% faster on chrome.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can make it easier

```
 addNames(names: ISomeInterface | ISomeInterface[]): void {
        this.names = this.names.concat(names);
 }
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

> The concat() method returns a new array comprised of the array on which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or **value(s)** provided as arguments.

Comment: Great example of how I am over-engineering something instead of properly reading specs... thanks! I will keep the other answer as accepted though since it has a bit of extra info about TS that people seem not to know and it gives you more flexibility as to how pass the parameters

Comment: Actually, this still compiles into error: `Error:(26, 46) TS2345: Argument of type 'ISomeInterface | ISomeInterface[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ISomeInterface'.
 Type 'ISomeInterface[]' is not assignable to type 'ISomeInterface'.`

Comment: @Tom I've updated `tsc` to `Version 1.9.0-dev.20160302` now it's working for me

Comment: Cool, I have still 1.8.7 but im gona believe you :) actually im gonna accept your answer I think its better considering the `...` that i mentioned in the other answer

Comment: I had the same question and I later found out a different syntax of doing this
addNames(names: ISomeInterface | Array<ISomeInterface>) just saying that this too works..

Comment: if `names` is not an array, it will duplicate it in the array:
`[names, names]`

Comment: You could also get that `not assignable` error if the initiate names inline like `[].concat`. After I initiated `names` with a proper type first as an empty array. The error went away.

Answer (score 22):

You could also use the rest parameter:

```
interface ISomeInterface {
    name: string;
}

class SomeClass {
    public names: ISomeInterface[] = []; // create an instance if applicable.

    addNames(...names: ISomeInterface[]): void {
        // the names argument will always be an array
        this.names = this.names.concat(names);
    }
}
```

You can call it like:

```
addNames(name1); // just pass one
addNames(name1, name2, name3); // pass more comma separated
addNames(...[name1, name2, name3]); // pass an array.
```

Please note that I removed the `function` keyword, because otherwise the `this` keyword inside the body block might lose scope depending on who's calling it.

Comment: Yes, beautiful, I did know about rest param but what I didn't know is that it compiles itself into params being always an array. thank you!

Comment: I didn't know rest parameters compiled down either. That is a neat solution!

Comment: @Tom I would also suggest instantiating the array as it would prevent you from doing `null` checks everywhere. `public names: ISomeInterface[] = [];`

Comment: @Silvermind yeah I did that, I just wrote this too quickly without checking if its all correct..

Comment: @Silvermind actually.... its still not 100%. Because of the `...` when supplying array, in cases when you dont know if your variable is array or single, the function returns wrong result. If I do addNames([name1, name2, name3]) the result is not correct. Not always I will be able to control if what is passing to function is single object or array, thus unable to add `...`

Comment: That should only be possible when passing an `any` or calling it 'outside' of typescript. In that case you would have to do type or instance checking.

Comment: Upvoted, this is the best solution IMO to pass "one or a list" of something to a function. Using a union type makes things unnecessarily cumbersome IMO.

Comment: The only problem I see is that it works even without any arguments, so addNames() compiles correctly... Do you see a way to force that the argument has at least length 1 ?

Comment: @user2010955 You could do something like `addNames(name: ISomeInterface, ...names: ISomeInterface[])`

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you want

```
interface ISomeInterface {
    name: string;
}

class SomeClass {
    public names: ISomeInterface[];

    addNames(names: ISomeInterface | ISomeInterface[]): void {
        names = (names instanceof Array) ? names : [names];
        this.names = this.names.concat(<ISomeInterface[]>names)
    }    
}
```

You want to use `instanceOf`, not isArray.

Comment: Sorry, not what I was asking for and your code still gives the same error

Answer (score 2):

The official way typescript handles this is with multiple function signatures, for example:

```
addNames(names: ISomeInterface): void;
addNames(names: ISomeInterface[]): void;
addNames(names: any): void {
    ...
}
```

You can see more information in the [official handbook here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions-overloads)

Comment: Yes thats what I thought, but then if you call `addNames("Hello World")` it doesn't throw any error, so basically you could just use `:any` declaration and it would be the same...

Comment: I think you just have to validate it yourself at that point. I am not sure how it would work but you could try replacing `names: any` with `name?: ISomeInterface, names?: ISomeInterface[]`. That should prevent passing a string but it would allow you to pass nothing or both also. Then inside the function use `names || [name]` and it would be pretty seamless.