# Accept Array of Interfaces OR single interface in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, interface

Really new in TypeScript. I have an array of presets that the user can add or modify existing ones. Since it has a couple of keys only, I made an interface.

```
interface IStylePreset {
    type : string;
    backgroundColor : string;
    color? : string
}
```

And the implementation is here:

```
static stylePresets : Array<IStylePreset> = [
    { type: "default", backgroundColor: "#37474f" , color: "#ECEFF1"},
    { type: "success", backgroundColor: "#37474f", color: "#ECEFF1" },
    { type: "error", backgroundColor: "#d32f2f", color: "#EEE"}
];
```

Now I have a config function that takes a custom preset to either change existing presets or add new ones.

```
static config = {
    types(newPresets) : void {
        newPresets = [].concat(newPresets);
        for(var i = 0, len = newPresets.length, current; i< len; i++){
            var pos = Message.Util.find(Message.stylePresets, newPresets[i].type)
            current = newPresets[i];
            if(pos !== -1) for(var key in current) Message.stylePresets[pos][key] = current[key];
            else Message.stylePresets[Message.stylePresets.length] = current;
            }
        }
    };
```

The problem is, I can't figure out what to specify in the type of `newPresets` since it's accepting both an array of objects and as well as a single object (which makes into a single element array `newPresets = [].concat(newPresets);`).

I'm trying to learn TypeScript and I don't know if what I'm doing is right. Can someone please help me out here? Further reading material or docs would be gold.

Comment: It was pointed out that the question is a duplicate so I'm voting it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a TypeScript [union type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types): `IStylePreset | IStylePreset[]`.

In the function body you can check with `Array.isArray()` whether an array or a single instance was passed. Actually, in this case, `concat()` does already check internally whether an array or an instance is concatenated so the solution is simple:

E.g.:

```
class Config {
    private presets: IStylePreset[] = [];

    public addPresets(presetOrArray: IStylePreset | IStylePreset[]) {
        // Concat will concat either Array or instance
        this.presets = this.presets.concat(presetOrArray);
    }

    public getPresets(): IStylePreset[] {
        return this.presets;
    }
}

let config = new Config();
config.addPresets(stylePresets);
config.addPresets(stylePresets[0]);
console.log(config.getPresets().length); // prints 4
```

Comment: Thanks! I was actually thinking on the same lines.. But I'm trying to avoid isArray when I can go for [].concat. Its 43% faster on chrome plus we stay dry because the code will be the same in both if and else except a few changes. Can you please confirm whether types(newPresets : IStylePreset | Array<IStylePreset>) will work? The compiler says its clean but I still am not sure whether it's correct or not.. Tried looking at the docs but can't find it..

Comment: Yes, IStylePreset[] and Array<IStylePreset> are just two different notations for the same thing. Good point regarding concat. Its actually more efficient than pushing in a foreEach-loop. I've modified the example above accordingly. You still need isArray to check whether an array or a single instance was passed.

Comment: if a single instance is passed, concat will make it into an array. if an array is passed, [].concat results in no changes. +1ing the answer. Will accept it after a while to see if there are better performance solutions to this. Thanks man!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. One newer stops learning new things when answering questions... In that case, the call to isArray is indeed unnecessary. Example adapted.

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

1) use the `any` type like this: `types(newPresets : any)`

or

2) keep the `IStylePreset[]` type (e.g. `types(newPresets : IStylePreset[])` and when passing a single object just wrap it in an array like this: `config.types([{ type: "default", backgroundColor: "#37474f" , color: "#ECEFF1"}]);`

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to avoid any. I think I may have found an alternative solution by using 
types(newPresets : IStylePreset | Array<IStylePreset>) : void {...
The compiler says its clean but I don't know if this is right.. Can you confirm it?

Comment: That sounds ok from the method signature point of view. Also, I just saw that your question is actually already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749833/typescript-function-taking-one-or-array-of-objects

Comment: Just saw it. Thanks!