# Typescript function accept a single string or an array of strings

Tags: javascript, typescript

The function below takes 2 arguments, a mandatory `tableName` and an optional `connectionName`:

```js
export const clearTable = async (
  tableName: string[],
  connectionName = 'default'
) => {
  try {
    const connection = getConnection(connectionName)
    const promises = tableName.map((table) =>
      connection.query(`DELETE FROM ${table}`)
    )
    await Promise.all(promises)
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(
      `Failed to clear table '${tableName}' on database '${connectionName}': ${error}`
    )
  }
}
```

Calling this function:

```js
clearTable(['table1', 'table2']) // works fine because it receives an array
clearTable('table3') // fails because it's not an array > TypeError: tableName.map is not a function
```

In one way or another it should be possible to convert a single `string` to an array of strings to be able to use the same logic with `array.map`. We've also looked at the [REST parameter](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/rest-parameters) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749833/typescript-function-taking-one-or-array-of-objects) but that seems to be not possible as a rest parameter can be zero or more and we need at least one.

What is the correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: `tableName: string | string[]`?

Comment: But then the `map` function wont work on `tablename` like `tablename.map()`.

Comment: @DarkLite1 Then your function needs to check the `typeof tableName` before deciding if it should be treated like a string or an array of strings.

Comment: Of course not, so you need to handle that in the runtime logic too. E.g. use `[tableName]` if it's not already an array.

Comment: Would it be possible to convert a single `string` to an `array` of `string`? I was hoping there would be a typescript way of doing this.

Comment: How would there be *"a typescript way"*? The types are all stripped out by the compiler, they don't exist at runtime. Any casting or conversion has to happen at the regular JS level.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I'll adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "Of course not" or "How would there be" is not the best expression if you keep in mind that we are at Stackoverflow a place where the questioner does not know everything. Its 100% valid to not have the same knowledge like everybody. Not knowing that typescript is stripped out at runtime can be explained straight without a negative touch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First modify parameter type from `string[]` to `string[] | string` and then in try block, when you assign value to `promises`, add the type check like so:
`Array.isArray(tableName)`.

```
export const clearTable = async (
  tableName: string[] | string,
  connectionName = 'default'
) => {
  try {
    const connection = getConnection(connectionName)
    const promises = Array.isArray(tableName) ?
      tableName.map((table) => connection.query(`DELETE FROM ${table}`))
      :
      connection.query(`DELETE FROM ${tableName}`))
    await Promise.all(promises)
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(
      `Failed to clear table '${tableName}' on database '${connectionName}': ${error}`
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I would rather convert a single string to an array of strings frist. But I'll figure it out. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Figured it out `if (typeof tableName === 'string') { tableName = [tableName] }`. Thanks again for putting me on the right path.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to break down the `string | string[] => string[]` problem to one function you can write the following and use it in multiple places:

```
function convert(param: string | string[]): string[] {
  return typeof param === 'string'
    ? [param]
    : param
}
```

Comment: I like this modular approach, makes it very convenient. Thank you for sharing :)